# Looping through an list object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I need to get a specific object out of a list by using a for loop

For example i would have this:

```
var list = [
  {Name: "Jake", Age: 15},
  {Name: "Paul", Age: 20}
];
```

Very simple right here but what i need to do is return the variable Name from each object, so that i should only get in this case Jake and Paul and not the age information. I know i can use a simple list[0].Name to give me an output but its more so in a case of a extreme amount of names that i would like to use a for-loop to loop through and return every name.

Comment: Map it with `Array#map`

Comment: For-loops are pretty simple. What is the issue you're having with the loop you've written? I'm assuming you've at least attempted this yourself.

Comment: Are you only wanting data pertaining to specific names? Whole question and whatever your specific problem is are not terribly clear. Take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: And if you think you can do this with a loop...then you should try that and ask questions when you have a real code problem. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective is for you to show your attempts to solve issue nd people help you with **your code** when it doesn't do what is expected

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is map:

```
const newList = list.map(function(element){
    return element.Name;
});
```

The map function iterates over an array and returns a new value for each iterated value.
In this case, the above function will return a new array with strings representing only the Name property of each object in the list.

For the same function, only with arrow notation and destructuring, please review:

```
const newList = list.map(({Name}) => Name);
```

Comment: If he's unaware of map, he probably doesn't know object destructuring and fat arrow functions. Would you mind providing a more es5-centric solution as well to help him understand?

Comment: @jas7457 sure, force of habit

Comment: Thanks! It helps demystify the shorter (and my preferred) es6 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple for-loop:

```js
var list = [{Name: "Jake", Age: 15}, {Name: "Paul", Age: 20}]

let names = [];

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  names.push(list[i].Name);
}

console.log(names);
```

Here's the same result with `forEach`:

```js
var list = [{Name: "Jake", Age: 15}, {Name: "Paul", Age: 20}]

let names = [];

list.forEach(function (obj) {
  names.push(obj.Name);
});

console.log(names);
```

Adding to Gilad's answer using `map` if you wanted to you could create a general function that will return the values of a specified object property so that you don't need to repeat code.

```js
var list = [{Name: "Jake", Age: 15}, {Name: "Paul", Age: 20}]

function getValue(key) {
  return function (obj) {
    return obj[key];
  }
}

let names = list.map(getValue('Name'));
let ages = list.map(getValue('Age'));

console.log(names, ages);
```

Comment: Well, this was a huge help!
Thanks for taking the time to help me out with this as i am new to coding and am also terribly sorry for not being more precise with my coding explanation and problems herein (To others who also chimed in to help!)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget an answer correct to aid other people who might visit this page looking for solutions.